# How to send a message when user says word in a sentence

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want the `sans` to be left alone, with the current code here it doesn't matter where sans, is it will activate. ex: `usansu`, I do not want that to work, I want it so sans only works while separate like ex: `u sans u`. I have commands that use "sans" in it and this gets in the way of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do that is to get the message and split it into words. Then you can check if the array contains the word "sans" without any extra characters.

**Example code:**

```js
bot.on ('message', function (message){
  const words = message.content.split(' ');

  if(words.includes('sans'))
  {
    message.channel.send("<:download:519723756403425294>");
  }
});
```